# loop different arrays javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello there am trying to save news tweets into three different array which are dynamically created.

am finding trouble when i want to get the text from each one of those array and make another request to twitter.

```
    news_tweets("reuters","1652541",3);
    function news_tweets(query, user_id,count) {
        news_array = [];
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&user_id=" + user_id + "&count="+count+
        "&callback=?",
        function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          var user = data[i].user.name;
          var date = data[i].created_at;
          var profile_img = data[i].user.profile_image_url;
          var text = data[i].text;
          var url = (data[i].entities.urls.length > 0 ? data[i].entities.urls[0].url : '');
          news_array[i] = [{user:user,date:date,profile_img:profile_img,text:text,url:url}];
        }  
      for (var i = 0; i < news_array.length; i++) {
          for (var x=0; x<i.length; x++){
              console.log(news_array[i][x].user);
              }
            }
        });
    }
```

It doesn't show anything on the console.log.

thanks for the help!!!!!

Comment: Please don't delete and re-ask your questions. You can edit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that your `count` is smaller than the `data` array's length, otherwise this could lead to some `undefined` values:

```
for (var i = 0; i < count && i < data.length; i++) …
```

Then, why are you creating all those one-element-arrays in the `news_array`? Just use only objects.

This would solve your actual issue: You are looping wrong over those inner arrays. The correct code would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < news_array.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < news_array[i].length; x++){
        console.log(news_array[i][x].user);
    }
}
```

Also, you should indent your code properly. You have some odd braces around, which don't make the code readable.

Comment: Bergi can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12446776/request-twitter-api-without-entering-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `x<i.length` in the `for` loop near the end. `i` is a number, so it doesn't have a `length`. You probably meant `x < news_array[i].length`.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following:

- Use the `push` method to append elements / data in your array `new_array`
- Use only 1 loop `for` to display the `user` value on console

So your code will be something like this:

```
news_tweets("reuters","1652541",3);

function news_tweets(query, user_id,count) {
    news_array = [];
    $.getJSON("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&include_rts=false&user_id=" + user_id + "&count="+count+
    "&callback=?",
        function (data) {
          for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
              var user = data[i].user.name;
              var date = data[i].created_at;
              var profile_img = data[i].user.profile_image_url;
              var text = data[i].text;
              var url = (data[i].entities.urls.length > 0 ? data[i].entities.urls[0].url : '');

              // Pushing your elements in your array, 1 by 1
              news_array.push({user:user,date:date,profile_img:profile_img,text:text,url:url});
        }  

        // Here you only need 1 loop!
        for (var i = 0; i < news_array.length; i++) {
            console.log(news_array[i][x].user);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing is i would loop the first one till data.length rather than count because its an api and it "might" or "might not" return all the data. So it will be fool proof to loop till data.length

And your problem is with i.length

```
for (var i = 0; i < news_array.length; i++) { 
    console.log(news_array[i].user);
}
```

this should work. not sure why you had to loop through a loop.